# ElasticSearch does not accept PUT command to a specific route

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to implement an rails application on my local machine that uses ElasticSearch. So I installed and used this command to setup ElasticSearch for the application:

`curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/dev-contacts-v3/_mapping" -d ' { "mappings" : { "_default_" : { "properties" : { " pin" : { "properties" : { "location" : { "type" : "geo_point" } } } } } } } '`.

But it returns an error:
`{"error":"ActionRequestValidationException[Validation Failed: 1: mapping type is missing;]","status":400}`

I realized the error only happens when I use the route `"http://localhost:9200/dev-contacts-v3/_mapping"` with this underline o `_mapping`.

Does anyone have any idea of the cause of this error?

Comment: You don't need to specify `.../mapping` or `/_mapping`, simply PUT on the index path and you're good since the payload you're sending contains a `"mappings":{...}`section already.

Answer (score 1):

The `_mapping` function allows you to see the existing mapping for a given index. If you want to define a mapping for a new index you can put a mapping using the index url:

```
PUT /dev-contacts-v3
{
   "mappings": {
      "_default_": {
         "properties": {
            "pin": {
               "properties": {
                  "location": {
                     "type": "geo_point"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

To see the mapping of an index:

```
GET /dev-contacts-v3/_mapping
```

On the same level as `mappings` you can specify `settings` where you describe the `filters`, `analyzers`, etc.. that can be used for you mappings.